# Looping through an entire array - all indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, xml, loops

For a task I need to display a list of albums' titles and all the songs. But I'm stuck only getting the first song to display for each album. How do I display them all? I assume I need to change the index value but I'm not sure how to write it to get all the values. My code is below.

```
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
     function loadDoc() {
     // This function will load the xml file and connect it to the webpage
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // This is used to exchange data with the server, allowing for parts of the page to change without reloading the page
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // This defines a function to be called when the readystate property changes
           if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           // This states that if the request is finished (readystate == 4) and the status returned is ok (this.staus == 200)
              extractSongs(this);
              // This runs the function to display the data from the xml file
           }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "CDLibrary.xml", true);
        // This gets the xml file
        xhttp.send();
        // This sends a request to the server 
     }
     function extractSongs(xml) {
     // This function will extract and display data from the xml file
      var i;
      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      // This returns the document containg a response to my request
      var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
      // This sets up the table
      var CdList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
      // This creates an array of the data from the xml file
       for (i = 0; i <CdList.length; i++) {
       // This will loop through the array by the number of cds in the array
         table += "<tr><td>" +
         CdList[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         "</td><td>" +
         CdList[i].getElementsByTagName("track")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         "</td></td>" ;
         // These display the elements by the tag name and generate them as table data
       }
      document.getElementById("CdCollection").innerHTML = table;
      // This gets the table from the html and makes it equal to the table from the javascript
     }  
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>My CD Collection</h1>

 <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get my collection</button>
 <br><br>
  <table id="CdCollection"></table>
   </body>
```

Comment: show me your xml file

Comment: <CDLibrary>
<CD>
<title>Adiemus: Songs of Sanctuary</title>
<performer>Karl Jenkins (composer)</performer>
<track>Adiemus</track> <duration>3:48</duration>
<track>Tintinnabulum</track> <duration>10:57</duration>
<track>Cantus Inaequalis</track> <duration>3:13</duration>
<track>Cantus Insolitus</track> <duration>5:35</duration>
This is just a snippet of the file, its basically the same all the way through.

Comment: it's only 1 item in list . how could you expect to print all the songs

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, do all the tracks need to be within the same tags?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml like this

Comment: I need to print all of the tracks for each CD, that example doesn't really apply here.

Comment: so you have different cd's in different xml ?

Comment: No, the whole xml file has different CDs on it. I need to display all the tracks of all the CDs. I can get all of their titles, but only the first track appears. I didn't post the whole thing because it was too long and I don't have the link to it.

Comment: if you are able to get all the titles then you should also get track if your xml file is well syntax.

Comment: That's the problem, I'm only getting the first track displayed from each album. Each track is listed like in the snippet I posted above.

Comment: add your xml file into your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you need a 2nd `for` loop for the for the `title`/`track`:-

```js
for (i = 0; i < CdList.length; i++) {

    var titleCount = CdList[i].getElementsByTagName("title").length;

    for (j = 0; j < titleCount; j++){

       // This will loop through the array by the number of cds in the array
       table += "<tr><td>" +
       CdList[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td><td>" +
       CdList[i].getElementsByTagName("track")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td></td>";
       // These display the elements by the tag name and generate them as table data
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't change the data displayed.